# Event Trigger Select2 when the select option is already selected (Multiple Select Option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a few select option like this :

```
<select class="competence">
    <option>Android</option>
    <option>PHP</option>
    <option>RoR</option>
    <option>Javascript</option>
</select>
```

and I want the option is disabled when the option is `already selected` in another select option.

my jquery look like this :

```
$('select.competence').on('change', function () {
    $('option').prop('disabled', false);
    $('select.competence').each(function () {
        var val = this.value;
        $('select.competence').not(this).find('option').filter(function () {
            return this.value == val;
        }).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

everything is works fine, until i tried to use `select2` plugin, so when i used `$('select.competence').select2()` , the `disabled` function is not work, i think the selector is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you would have to `selector.select2('destroy')` and then reinitialize the select2 see if this is what you were asking for, I assume that you have multiple selects with same value options.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.competence').on('change', function() {
    var allSelects = $('.competence');
    allSelects.find('option').prop('disabled', false);
    allSelects.each(function() {
      var currSelect = $(this);
      allSelects.not(currSelect).find('option').each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == currSelect.val()) {
          $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    });
    $('.competence').select2("destroy").select2();
  });
  $(".competence").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="competence">
    <option value='android'>Android</option>
    <option value='php'>PHP</option>
    <option value='ror'>RoR</option>
    <option value='javascript'>Javascript</option>
</select>

<select class="competence">
    <option value='android'>Android</option>
    <option value='php'>PHP</option>
    <option value='ror'>RoR</option>
    <option value='javascript'>Javascript</option>
</select>

<select class="competence">
    <option value='android'>Android</option>
    <option value='php'>PHP</option>
    <option value='ror'>RoR</option>
    <option value='javascript'>Javascript</option>
</select>
```